# Wifi disconnects automatically in Ubuntu 16.04, doesn't show networks

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I'm dual booting Win10 /Ubuntu 16.04. In windows 10,I can easily connect to my college wifi and stay connected,but in Ubuntu, it will connect to the network once,then it disconnects automatically and then it will not show the network,visible in my phone.

PS:i can connect to mobile wifi hotspot indefinitely , or to normal wifi

$ sudo lshw -class network
 *

```
-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 50:7b:9d:18:f6:7e
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d1204000-d1204fff memory:d1200000-d1203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 93
       serial: b4:6d:83:1e:d3:c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-32-generic firmware=17.608620.0 ip=192.168.43.50 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:52 memory:d1100000-d1101fff
```

Comment: It might be a bug with the wireless driver; are you using the latest kernel? I would [follow the steps here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) to see if updating to the latest "hardware enablement" kernel helps.

Comment: $ uname -r
4.13.0-32-generic

Comment: @mpontillo  Already the newest version

Comment: Are you using one of the official kernels? I thought Ubuntu 16.04 official kernels were 4.4.0; my Bionic (18.04) is on 4.13.0...